# SQL join using alias using calculated column

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have one table which has columns of last 10 years. I am trying to fetch the current year column but getting error.

Table ABC:

[image]

```
select a.*, b.year(getdate())
from d1 a 
  left join ABC b on a.name = b.name
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: can you give example of what you want to retrieve?

Comment: Cannot find either column "b" or the user-defined function or aggregate "b.year", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: With a properly normalized model this would be a really easy query

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query which unpivots the individual year columns into 2 columns, yr and yr_val.  When the yr=year(getdate()) the current year value will be returned.  GMB's query with the unpivot.

```
select a.*
from d1 a 
     cross apply
     (values (2018, a.[2018]),
             (2019, a.[2019]),
             (2020, a.[2020]),
             (2021, a.[2021]),
             (2022, a.[2022]),
             (2023, a.[2023]),
             (2024, a.[2024])) v(yr, yr_val)
where v.yr=year(getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, you can't have a query dynamically choosing which column it should return. A query returns a *fixed* set of columns, and the database needs to know that at the time it parses the query, before executing it.

You could work something out with dynamic SQL - but it seems like it just makes things unecessarily complicated.

A far better option would be to change your data model, in order to store each value in a separate row rather than in columns:

```
name    year    value
A       2018    18
A       2019    24
A       2020    72
B       2018    38
B       2019    19
B       2020    76
```

Then, the query is as easy as:

```
select * from mytable where year = year(getdate())
```